# How to deal exception in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a pagination request ，each page are many items . Sometimes my scrapy occur error result it stop. I do know the next page's url ,I want record this error and continue.
How can I ingore exception?

spider

```py
    def start_requests(self):
        url = ""
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            callback=self.parse, errback=self.error_back)


   def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
       if response.body:
          ...
          yield item
       
       yield next_page_request()
```

I want to record which page failed so that I could retry manual, here is my middleware

MySpiderMiddleware

```py
class MySpiderMiddleware:
        def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        # Called when a download handler or a process_request()
        # (from other downloader middleware) raises an exception.

        # Must either:
        # - return None: continue processing this exception
        # - return a Response object: stops process_exception() chain
        # - return a Request object: stops process_exception() chain
        body = dict(url=request.url, body=request.body.decode("utf8"), method=request.method, error=repr(exception))
        return Response(url=request.url, status=1000, body=to_bytes(json.dumps(body)))
```

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'cirium.middlewares.MySpiderMiddleware': 543,
}
```

the problem is that once request downloader failed , they raise exception and stop all spider ,the `parse` method won't be invoked , no more next request.

In addition， middlewate doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

> SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {    'cirium.middlewares.MySpiderMiddleware':
> 543, }

> class AircraftSpiderMiddleware:

The middleware name you entered is 'MySpiderMiddleware', and the class name is 'AircraftSpiderMiddleware'. Change it and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, It is an error but not mainly.It turns out download middware works better for me then spider middware. I have changed the description as you said and my soluction.

Comment: @Liamlin what error do you get? (item_error? spider_error? ...)

Comment: Connect timeout error, It seems downlad error

Answer (score 0):

I used downloader middleware, overwrite it's `process_exception`  method, which will be invoked when exception occured.
In this method ,I return a normal Response with special status.

The Response will be deal in my Request's callback method. In this callback method ,I could't tell respinse by status.

I'm wondering if it's graceful.